# run code if user is currently holding a key

Tags: keyboard, batch-file

I am currently making a program in batch, and I need to have a line of code that runs when the user is holding down a key (this code is run every frame). I don't want to make something that waits for the key to be pressed, because the loop it is in is the one that renders things (it is a game, so it needs to be updated constantly).

Comment: "It is a game". Sorry, what? In batch! At least use something like Autohotkeys.

Comment: A way to do this potentially is with [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and using the [HotKeySet](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm) function to call another user defined function such as this for example: `HotKeySet("<key>", "<Func>")` and then have the user defined function call the batch script perhaps or just run logic from it to do whatever the batch script does. Sometimes you have to get innovative and mix different technologies for certain solutions—I get paid to do this a lot. I love to hear something is not possible and make it happen.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Batch scripts are not meant to be run continuously and query at the same time. Batch files are scripts to run programs one row at a time.

If you want this kind of scripting, use something like vbscript or an actual program language.

Comment: [Snake.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741) disagrees.

Comment: @AveYo the way its done here in snake.bat is outside of the scope of SuperUser though or requires a third-party program.

Comment: It's exactly in the scope of the OP question. And it works just fine with no external program whatsoever, just a minor flickering, that can also be solved if running Windows 10 via built-in option.   Instead of correcting your "this is not possible" answer, or at least back-paddle out of it, you go on the other extreme